# Electromechanical buzzer—sound intensity control

Tags: circuit-design

The electromagnetic buzzer (with a low AC voltage coil — see image) in our home intercom terminal is so loud that it shocks us every time it buzzes.

I would like the sound to gradually increase to maximum volume as to avoid the abruptness of buzzing in full volume from the start. Or if that is too complex, permanently reduce the sound intensity.

In principle, will a simple circuit — capacitor connected in parallel to the buzzer — do the trick? I was assuming that initially, while the capacitor is being charged, less current flows through the buzzer coil, reducing the sound intensity until the capacitor is fully charged. will this work? why not? is there another simple way to achieve the same?

Otherwise, if I just wanted to make the buzzing sound less loud (no gradual change as described above), would a resistor do the trick? should the resistor be connected in parallel (reducing the current to the coil) or connected in series (reducing the voltage over the coil)?

The measured buzzer coil impedance is 8.6 Ω. I've attached a screenshot of the AC voltage applied to the buzzer as it is captured by an oscilloscope.

[image: Captured Waveform]

[image: Buzzer]

Comment: Only the transducer is shown - driving circuitry is not. The answer to many OP's questions is affected by the way this buzzer is driven. My best guess is that a series resistor can reduce sound level. If you don't wish to do electrical modification, consider a mechanical solution by adding a soft membrane between flapper and round pole piece

Comment: Best way to replace buzzer. Reduce volume you may mechanicaly, some damper, but results is not predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the photo of your buzzer, I think that the simplest and without any additional means solution is to move the plate a little further away by slightly bending it.

Answer (score 3):

These buzzers are often installed into a resonant chamber or acoustically coupled to the front panel radiating surface. Both provide amplification.

The resonant chamber can be acoustically damped with something like fibreglass wool.

Decoupling to the front panel requires remounting the buzzer on rubber or similar material.

Answer (score 2):

You may try a 1N4007 diode in series with the buzzer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on current, a small-value NTC (negative temperature coefficient) thermistor such as [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-BC-Components/NTCLE100E3338JB0?qs=Ar3ZMG0WdUL4%252BassWUiGug%3D%3D) in series *might* work. When cold, the resistance is high, and as it warms, it drops, making the buzzer louder. But that depends on the current to the coil, and the open-circuit voltage. If not enough power is dissipated in the thermistor, it won't warm enough to bring up the volume of the buzzer.

Answer (score 1):

Buzzers of the design shown often create much of their noise from impact of the metal arm with the solenoid core, followed by ringing on release.  The AC drive controls the frequency and force of the impacts.

Adding a series resistor should decrease the impact force/volume, but you might find that you get at least as good a result from adding 1 or 2 pieces of PVC insulating tape to the top of the core where the arm impacts.  Similarly, a strip or two on the top of the arm might well reduce the higher frequency vibrations.